# AVAssetWriterInput crash

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I am recording a trailing buffer of video.  At 15 second intervals, I am creating a new instance of `AVAssetWriter`, and adding my instance of `AVAssetWriterInput` as an input.  I am grabbing frames using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, and adding them like this:

`[writerInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer]`

This works fine most of the time, but occasionally the app will crash with this error message:

`*** -[CFDictionary removeObjectForKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x96b28a0`

What does this error message even mean?  Might it mean that the `AVAssetWriter` has been deallocated?  Or does it mean that the `AVAssetWriterInput` has been deallocated?  Something else?

Thanks,

James

Comment: Are you sure you can reuse AVAssetWriterInput like that? Does [AVAssetWriter canAddInput:] have anything to say?

Comment: doesn't seem to be the problem.  thanks though.  I will repost when I figure it out though.

Answer (score 0):

The message removeObjectForKey:  was sent to an instance of CFDictionary (possibly an NSDictionary) with address 0x96b28a0.  That instance had already been deallocated, but a pointer to it was still being used by the code.

If you were running with zombies enabled (aka NSZombiesEnabled), the system will track deallocated objects and keep references long enough to detect using dangling pointers.

Knowing that you are over-releasing an object is easier than finding the incorrect release.  Plenty has been written on the subject.